# How do I create a function that accepts multiple arguments to perform an arithmetic calculation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, math

I want to write a function that performs arithmetic on ALL the arguments supplied. So for instance, if I do:

`calculate('+', 3, 5, 6)`

It should return 14 (which is 3+5+6)

Or if I do

`calculate('*', 6,3,6,8,)`

It should return 864 (which is the equivalent of multiplying all those numbers).

The function should essentially be able to handle any amount of numbers I supply to it, while also being able to handle the main arithmetic operators such as + - / *

I'm new at programming. I've tried:

```
function mCalc(_operator){
  if(_operator=='+'){
    return arguments + arguments;
  }

}
console.log(mCalc('+',5,5));
```

this is not working so i can't even move forward.

Answer (score 5):

In each function you have an [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) see the section **Rest, default, and destructured parameters** as it states:

> The arguments object can be used in conjunction with rest, default, and destructured parameters.
>
> `function foo(...args) { return args; }`

Once you have all the arguments which are needed for your calculation just use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). As the documentation which states:

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

I guess you can use as the following:

```js
const mCalc = (_operator, ...args) => {
  if(_operator === '+') {
      return args.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
  }

  // rest what you want to implement
}

const result = mCalc('+', 3, 5, 6, 2);

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you . This really helps me to understand more. only i need to declare a function that can take random arguments to be calculated.

Comment: function mCalc (_operator, ...args)  {
    if(_operator == '+') {
        return args.reduce((a, c) => a + c );
    }
    else if(_operator == '-'){
        return args.reduce((a, c) => a - c );  
    }
    else if(_operator == '*'){
        return args.reduce((a, c) => a * c );  
    }
    else if(_operator == '/'){
        return args.reduce((a, c) => a / c );  
    }
  
    
  }
  
  
  console.log(mCalc('/',20 ,5 ));

Comment: after polishing i got that. it works perfect. sorry for the way it is presented. im new to this stacksoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object for the operators and reduce the values by using a function which returns a function for two operands.

By calling the function the operator is taken and the values are taken to an array by using [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

This approach uses [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), like

```
calculate = (op, ...values) => values.reduce(take(op));
^^^^^^^^^                                               name of the function/variable
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                             parameters
                            ^^                          arrow
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  return value
```

```js
const
    operators = {
        '+': (a, b) => a + b,
        '*': (a, b) => a * b
    },
    take = op => operators[op],
    calculate = (op, ...values) => values.reduce(take(op));

console.log(calculate('+', 3, 5, 6)); // 14
console.log(calculate('*', 6, 3, 6, 8));
```

Comment: wow that was faster than i thought it would be. Thanks so much. i'm getting more understanding. Where did you declare calculate as a function?

Comment: yea this code makes sense. works perfect..my understanding opened. wise man! stay blessed